# Creating Custom Vector Maps for Javascript Vector Mapping Apps

Tags: javascript, maps, jqvmap

I'm looking to create custom maps for a web app that I'm developing.

I'm looking at datamaps (http://datamaps.github.com/), Kartograph.js (http://kartograph.org/), and JQVMap (http://jqvmap.com/).

I can create the maps using CorelDraw, but how do I export it so that I can use it with these tools?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created http://svgto.jvectormap.com/ for that purpose. With it you can convert SVG files to maps compatible with [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com).

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh Insert SVG code to the textarea and press "Convert to map" button, edit id and name of the regions if you want, then press "Save".

Comment: @ObinwanneHill - Hi, I looked at your page, and it does not seem to work for me .. What SVG version should one use ? ( basic, tiny , 1.1 1.2 etc ..) also , Does the code need to inclde the XML tags ?

Answer (score 2):

How you get SVG code? Import your svg graphic to this editor:
[https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html)

Then you can edit code (keyboard shortcut U) and paste it to **bjornd** site:
http://svgto.jvectormap.com/